# Coverting class component to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am currently woring in class based component. Now as class based component are now outdated so i want to convert them into functional based component
So can someone help me with this
Below is my code:

```
    class Map extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.map = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
          zone: "Zone2",
          polygon: null,
          index: 0,
          zoneIndex: null,
          center: { lat: 11.174036305817275, lng: 76.3754534171875 },
        };
      }
      componentDidMount = () => {
        let a= {office_id: 934};
    }
_polyRef = (ref) => {
    polygonRef.push(ref);
  };
  overlay = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      drawingControlEnabled: false,
    });
```

Also This is quite confusing for me that how to convert render method to functional component

```
render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap((props) => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.map = ref;
        }}
        
      >
        {this.state.addNewZone === true && (
        <DrawingManager
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google?.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [google?.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
            },
          }}
         
        />)}
      
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
       
        <div>
          <GoogleMapExample/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [convert react class-based to functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69965343/convert-react-class-based-to-functional-component)

For your Map component it should look like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

function GoogleMapExample() {
    return null;
}

// Map.js
const Map = (props) => {
    const map = useRef();
    const [zone, setZone] = useState('Zone2');
    const [polygon, setPolygon] = useState(null);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [zoneIndex, setZoneIndex] = useState(null);
    const [center, setCenter] = useState({lat: 11.174036305817275, lng: 76.3754534171875});

    const [drawingControlEnabled, setDrawingControlEnabled] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let a = {office_id: 934};
    }, []);

    const polyRef = (ref) => {
        let polygonRef; // ?
        polygonRef.push(ref);
    };


    const overlay = () => {
        setDrawingControlEnabled(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMapExample/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Maybe it will help you, to do the GoogleMapExample component your self.

If you want to change a render of a class component to a function component, you basically return your JSX code (see above).

Just like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Your HTML
        </div>
    );
};


class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Your HTML
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

- State hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Effect hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thanks for help But i didnt got your point correctly for render (). Please look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoneshow-s3qvyj?file=Map.js and can you please help me with this to convert the render() into functional component

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://olinations.medium.com/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139